# Faster way to specify character array filling?

Tags: java, arrays, char

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ArraySpecification {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[] correctLetters = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
        Arrays.fill(correctLetters, 0, 1, 'z');
        Arrays.fill(correctLetters, 2, 3, 'z');
        Arrays.fill(correctLetters, 4, 5, 'z');
        System.out.println(correctLetters);
    }
}
```

I just wanted to ask if there is any way this can be done faster and more efficient?

Comment: That looks like a micro optimization. You should not worry about it until you demonstrate it has performance issues demonstrated by usage of a profiler.

Comment: And what do you want `correctLetters` to print?

Comment: `correctLetters[0] =correctLetters[2] =correctLetters[4] ='z'`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is but not that great instead of paying the cost/overhead of calling a static method you can directly change the char using the array index which guarantees `O(1) speed`:

**sample:**

```
        char[] correctLetters = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
        correctLetters[0] = 'z';
        correctLetters[2] = 'z';
        correctLetters[4] = 'z';
```

Comment: The optimization (little that it is) isn't the reason to write the code like this -- this is far more readable than having to remember how `Arrays.fill` works, and why it would only be done for one index at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless you elaborate more on the required logic for having specific letter (e.g. `'z'`) at specific index, nothing much can be said.

Why bother at all about `Arrays.fill` ? Just initialize the array as you want :) !

```
char[] correctLetters = {'z','b','z','d','z'};
```

Comment: I wanted to fill them. The starting letters were just there.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same result with this loop, which I think is simpler :

```
for (int i = 0; i < correctLetters.length; i += 2) {
    correctLetters[i] = 'z';
}
```